# How to make periodic table in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to create an app that show periodic table but I don't know how to do that simply. one way i thought was UICollectionView but it is not good way. I want to know what can I search and look for.
Thank You !

Comment: Please include more information about what you'd like to do and include code of what you've researched and tried before that you'd like help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you're talking about the periodic table of elements?

A `UICollectionView` is indeed a good way. You should watch the keynote of the 2017 WWDC. They demonstrate that very thing using new features of `UICollectionView` added in iOS 11, but you could do it without those new features as well.

Comment: Thank you @Duncan C